# how to display the value stored in db (its a boolean - true/ false) as check box in .erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

Currently my code looks like this, all the values are shown in a table & I am directly printing true / false values. Instead I want show true / false values as checked / un-checked state of check box:

```
   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.is-admin %></div>
    <td><%= user.active_status %></div>
    </tr>
   <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) helper:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.username %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'admin', '1', user.is_admin, :disabled => true %></div>
    <td><%= user.active_status %></div>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
<td><%= user.username %></td>
<td><%= user.email %></td>
<td>Is Admin: <%= check_box_tag 'user', 'is_admin', user.is_admin, :disabled => true %></div>
<td><%= user.active_status %></div>
</tr>
```

disabled is used to grey out the checkbox so that someone cant change the value coz as per the usability there is no form to submit.

Comment: this worked for me but the last bracket (`)`) needs to be removed

Answer (score 0):

You can add this,

```
<%= check_box_tag :active_status, user.id, user.active_status, :disabled => true %>
```